# Cannot generate a new CSR in git bash

Tags: git, bash, openssl, mingw-w64

I'm trying to generate SSL on [Get Https For Free](https://gethttpsforfree.com/)

And I'm following stepts on git bash(git version 2.9.3.windows.2, mingw64) but stucked on a **step 2**, **Certificate Signing Request**.

I typed command following

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.key -subj "/" -reqexts SAN -config <(cat /d/Git/usr/ssl/openssl.cnf  <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:dev.xn--p89al22awxc7t2ajoa.com,DNS:dev.stocktalk.kr"))
```

However, an error is annoying me.

This is error. What is the problem and how can I generate successfully?

```
error on line -1 of /proc/3028/fd/63
7656:error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process:bss_file.c:175:fopen('/proc/3028/fd/63','rb')
7656:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:178:
7656:error:0E078072:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:no such file:conf_def.c:195:
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) Both us an OpenSSL FILE, so you won't need the extra redirections.

Comment: @jww Oh, I've got it. thanks you for your recommend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the fancy stdin redirection for openssh config does not work, try as a workaround to:

- copy `/d/Git/usr/ssl/openssl.cnf` somewhere else
- edit it (or apply your `sed`'s) on that new file
- use the file directly in your openssh command:

  ```
   openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.key -subj "/" -reqexts SAN -config new_edited_file
  ```

Regarding the error `Error Loading request exception section SAN`, the [OP Minkyu Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819624/minkyu-kim) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160884/cannot-generate-a-new-csr-in-git-bashmingw64/39161095#comment65665702_39161095) following "[Multi-Domain SSL Setup with “Subject Alternative Names”](https://easyengine.io/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/ssl/multidomain-ssl-subject-alternative-names/)", adding:

```
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = www.example.com
DNS.2 = example.com
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it, but and error `Error Loading request extion section SAN` occured. but I find a page what helps me. https://easyengine.io/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/ssl/multidomain-ssl-subject-alternative-names/ I followed steps, I succeeded.

Comment: @MinkyuKim Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.